# Common Pitfalls of filing NPA submission at USPTO

Tags: filing, non-provisional

I am planning to file a non provisional application that is due this month 18-April.  I intend to try e-file the NPA on Friday the 12th so as to have some time incase something does not go favorably.  I am researching the [pitfalls of filing](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=USPTO%20common%20%20pitfalls&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) and would seek any lesson-learned or a good pitfalls checklist I could review to better prepared filer.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Extremely broad question. Are you concerned about the mechanics and administrative issues or the substance of the application? A trivial, short, answer is hire a professional.

Comment: Good point.  This question is posed from the standpoint of mechanics and administrative facets of submitting the application: not the substance (content of the application).

Answer (score 1):

Some last minute things you might check are that -

you are filing a specification, claims and drawings. The first sentence of the application needs to **correctly** claim priority to previous applications and incorporate them by reference if that is desirable (that is *not* fixable after filing without refiling). Every item in a drawing that has a reference number in the drawing should have that reference number in the text of the specification. Make sure you do not duplicate reference numbers for different items. If you do not have a customer number yet, I recommend getting one so you can track your application on line.